# Spring Boot Application is not running , Getting error

Tags: java, spring-boot

**When I am trying to change java version from java 8 to java 17 then I am getting below Exception.  I also changed My spring boot version previously I was using spring boot 1.3.3.RELEASE version. Please help me.**

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup*  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:232)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:245)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
> at
> com.aujas.keystore.microservice.KeystoreController.main(KeystoreController.java:43)
> *Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)*
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> ... 5 more

**Here is my porm.xml file.**

4.0.0

```
<groupId>codesign</groupId>
<artifactId>microservice</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>microservice</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.12</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.49</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.paluch.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-gelf</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.RC1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

**I have Updated latest dependencies as well**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.49</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Provide code snippets to look at.

Comment: You need to update dependency version also that support java 17.

Comment: I did scanning on your pom.xml file and it showed that those dependencies might not be working well with java 17, you might wanna consider upgrading them or set their scope to provided and place their jars in the repository in your .m2

javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0


org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-processing:2.19


org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.20


com.sun.jersey:jersey-client


biz.paluch.logging:logstash-gelf:1.11.2

Comment: I have updated the dependency with latest version but getting same error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.7 is not the version you want for Java 17. You need Spring Boot 3.

After that, you're pretty much on your own for now, things can still go wrong depending on classloading issues, dependency injection inconsistencies, etc. etc.

I've been working on porting something from Java 8 to 17 that's Spring Boot based for a while now, and it's not quite smooth sailing. The migration guides provided help, but if you have combinations of dependencies that are outside the mainstream they will only get you so far. And without much more information to be provided by you nobody is going to be able to tell you more.